# Raspberry pi with SIM7600E not connecting to internet automatically after reboot

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi4

Please note that I have a Raspberry pi 4 and a SIM7600E-H1C module and I want my Raspberry pi to be connected to the internet all the time. So I used the SIM7600 module, plugged in and inserted the SIM card. I can provide internet to Raspberry pi using this command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF0NB.jpg)
and the IP of both SIM7600 and Raspberry pi must match in order to use the internet, for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY8bc.jpg)
but my problem is When the Raspberry pi Reboot and turn it back on Refuses to connect automatically as expected So I have to re-enter the sudo command every time my computer reboots.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpZ9J.jpg)
I want SIM7600E works like an aircard that inserts a SIM card and plugs it in to use the internet right away. Can anyone help me with this? Or is there a way to set the IP somewhere?

I follow this website https://www.elementzonline.com/blog/accessing-internet-(jio-sim)-in-sim7600-4g-modem-v2.0-with-Raspberry-pi-using-qmi-interface

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about programming. You should ask on [raspberrypi.se]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.